# prepared for it

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

In Russell’s essay he put

> “To bear misfortune well when it comes, it is wise to have cultivated in happier times a certain width of interests, so that the mind may find prepared for it some undisturbed place.”

It seems to me that the *prepared for it* part should be placed after *some undisturbed place*, so that it makes a more natural sequence for me. Why did he write like that? Is it an inversion or what?

Comment: Your version would be the standard way of saying it. Russell's way is more formal. It's a similar inversion to "*cultivated in happier times **a certain width of interests***", which normally would read, "*cultivated **a certain width of interests** in happier times*". Can't speak to the grammar rules that allow these particular inversions though

Comment: While reading him, actually not just him, I’ve noticed that sometimes preposition phrases would be placed in front of a sentence, just like the one you quoted, but normally we may just put them at the end.